# Conditional rendering in React; is this THE way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was just looking into React to compare it to my go-to framework Vue and I was trying to conditionally render a button. When I looked into how to do this I made this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { likes: 0 }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>
          Likes: {this.state.likes}
        </button>
        {
          this.state.likes > 0 ? (
            <button onClick={this.reset}>
              Unlike
            </button>
          ) : ('')
        }
      </div>
    )
  }

  increment = () => this.setState({ likes: this.state.likes + 1 })
  reset     = () => this.setState({ likes: 0 })
}
```

Is this REALLY the way to go? I feel like the syntax is very very ugly, atleast compared to Vue with it's v-if and v-show directives. Or is there a better way to achieve this in a clean way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the conditional rendering look a bit nicer by using `&&` instead of the conditional operator:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { likes: 0 }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>
          Likes: {this.state.likes}
        </button>
        {
          this.state.likes > 0 && (
            <button onClick={this.reset}>
              Unlike
            </button>
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }

  increment = () => this.setState({ likes: this.state.likes + 1 })
  reset     = () => this.setState({ likes: 0 })
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

But an even better improvement IMO would be to use a functional component instead of messing with objects and prototype methods, it makes things a lot more concise:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [likes, setLikes] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setLikes(likes + 1)}>
        Likes: {likes}
      </button>
      {
        likes > 0 && (
          <button onClick={() => setLikes(0)}>
            Unlike
          </button>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

If you have multiple areas with conditional logic, you can separate them out into separate components for readability:

```js
const Unlike = ({ setLikes }) => (
  <button onClick={() => setLikes(0)}>
    Unlike
  </button>
);
const App = () => {
  const [likes, setLikes] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setLikes(likes + 1)}>
        Likes: {likes}
      </button>
      {
        likes > 0 && <Unlike setLikes={setLikes} />
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: Very cool! I see React is very flexible in ways you can use it :). Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

For the most part yes. You can simplify the statement though, you can use logical `&&` instead of the ternary operator `?` if you wish to display the data only in condition and nothing in the other.

```js
this.state.likes > 0 && (
   <button onClick={this.reset}>Unlike</button
)
```

Additionally I'd like to point out, while this is not directly a use-case for your example, you can forgo the optional render if blocks in the return by having multiple returns in render (eg. a real life example with loader)

```js
render() {
  if (isFetchingData) {
     return <Loader />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      My component
    </div>
  )
}
```

But on a more personal note, I genuinely think you'll get used to the syntax. It's probably not as elegant on the first sight as vue, but it actually allows you to have more powerful logic inside the render method by clearly separating javascript from html.

Answer (score 2):

For inline rendering you could do

```
{
  this.state.likes > 0 &&
  <button onClick={this.reset}>Unlike</button>;
}
```

or in your render function

```
let like = null;
if (this.state.likes > 0) {
    like = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
}
```

and then

```
<div>
  <button onClick={this.increment}>Likes: {this.state.likes}</button>
  {like}
</div>;
```

I personally prefer the second but it's up to you

more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

The main beauty of react comes when you start splitting your code into functions. So May be you can have a function called  `renderButton()` and let it decide what to render.

```
renderButton = () => {
// all code logic here
 if(this.state.likes > 0){
   return (<button>Unlike</button>)
 }
  return (<></>)
}
```

then in render function you can just {`this.renderButton`}

also you can do `condition && statement`.

You can also read about pure components which only contains the UI and the logic is written in some other component. There are many ways to write beautiful and clean code in react.

The main problem is that react is easy to start with and therefore many new developers will start writing code that is difficul to read.

Also i forgot to mention hooks which makes writing react much cleaner and easier.