# Show p tag only if value is passed by props

Tags: reactjs

Would require your assistance in order to show a p tag **only** if value is given in the API. I receive my data from API, and sometimes the field has values and sometimes not, therefore if the item has no feed, there is an error raised `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'substring')`

I don't know how to check if there is no data into this field `{threat.attributes.timestamp.substring(0, 10)}`, because if is blank, I want to hide the entire p tag, as the field became redundant will null value.

Thank you in advance!

```
<div>

  <p className="post__author--role">
     <small>Timestamp: {threat.attributes.timestamp.substring(0, 10)}
     </small>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional rendering in React; is this THE way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729326/conditional-rendering-in-react-is-this-the-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish [conditional rendering in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) using a couple of ways

1. Inline If with Logical && Operator
   (Since your variable is kinda long, I refactored them to a separate variable)

```
const data = threat.attributes.timestamp;
<div>
  <p className="post__author--role">
     {data && <small>Timestamp: {data.substring(0, 10)} </small>}
  </p>
</div>
```

Thanks to short circuiting, this will only render your `<small>` element if  `threat.attributes.timestamp` exists

2. Ternary operators

Ternary operator is kind of another way to do inline If

```
const data = threat.attributes.timestamp;
<div>
  <p className="post__author--role">
     <small>Timestamp: {data ? data.substring(0, 10) : null}
     </small>
  </p>
</div>
```

You can replace the `null` with something you want to display in case of no data, for example: `<span>No timestamp</span>`

3. Optional chaining

```
<div>
  <p className="post__author--role">
     <small>Timestamp: {threat.attributes.timestamp?.substring(0, 10)}
     </small>
  </p>
</div>
```

With optional chaining, the whole expression will return `undefined` if `.timestamp` fails to exist

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick! u rock @Bao Huynh Lam